# Install Ubuntu alongside Windows XP, is this possible on a 2001 system?

Tags: installation, windows-xp

My Windows XP is not going to be servicing security updates anymore after 2014, is it possible to download Ubuntu/Linux on my current system and transfer all current files to Ubuntu?

I would like to Install Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just choose „Install anlongside Windows“ when the installer asks you.
After installing Ubuntu you can easily access the Windows partition from within Ubuntu and transfer your files to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your system should be perfectly fine for the standard Ubuntu. ...But, the beauty of all the Ubuntu variants is that you can try them all without installing. You can put each on a CD/DVD or USB stick and try them out first.

I think you will find both [Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/download) and [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) too slow on your hardware but feel free to give them a try.

[Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) is a lighter desktop which should be reasonably fast on your machine. This would be my personal choice.

The lightest desktop is [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) which should be really fast for you.

Comment: Source: http://askubuntu.com/questions/263191/what-ubuntu-for-windows-xp